# UE4 Test if pawn is controlled pawn

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I made up a C++ ThirdPersonExample project. I added several ThirdPersonCharacter BP. (TPC BP) I added a variable to the TPC BP.

I play as one of the TPC BP's. The other ones are controlled by AI.

In Event Graph of TPC BP, on Event BeginPlay, I want to set a variable if this current instantiated TPC BP is the controlled pawn - ie it's me playing!

I see that you can set variables.

[image: sample of setting variable]

However:

1. I only want to set a variable if I'm not the Controlled Pawn
2. I want to also set another variable if I am the Controlled Pawn.

I may be thinking of this the wrong way...any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution would be:

1. Add `Event Possessed` to *TCP BP*. This should be fired when your pawn (character) is possessed by a controller.
2. Since previously mentioned event has parameter - **reference** to a **possessing controller**, you can then try to cast that reference to **PlayerController** and **AIController** ( or their descendants).
3. Final step is to implement specific code for both types of possessing controllers (when cast was successful).